# How to write SelectionChanged event for FlowDocumentScrollViewer

Tags: c#, wpf, selectionchanged, flowdocumentscrollviewer

How to write selection changed event for FlowDocumentScrollViewer in c#?

When the user select or deselect text in FlowDocumentScrollViewer, I do want to fire some event. My goal is to display in an statusbar the selection length.

How can I do that?

Please help. Thank You.

Comment: [TextSelection.Changed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.textselection(v=vs.110).aspx) event on [FlowDocumentScrollViewer.Selection property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.flowdocumentscrollviewer.selection(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: This may be a good start.
But it's still not enough, because before the user has selected - the selection is nothing.